# Dynamically adding and removing Components form element in Angular

Tags: angular

I have created a component that represents a select box using Angular Material. This component receives a FormGroup as input and works correctly when placed within another component. I need to enable the addition and removal of this component using buttons. I have managed to make it work using ViewContainerRef.createComponent and can pass the parameters needed to dynamically populate the select's content. However, I am encountering the error 'ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'control2'.'

**Parent component**

```
import { STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS } from "@angular/cdk/stepper";
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "gcr-create",
  template: `<gcr-select-form
                [formGroup]="form"
                formControlName="control1"
                otherParam="OK"
              ></gcr-select-form>
            </div>
            <ng-template #containerMoreSelect></ng-template>
              <button mat-stroked-button (click)="click()">Add More</button>`,
  styles: [``],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { showError: true },
    },
  ],
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("containerMoreSelect", {
    read: ViewContainerRef,
  })
  containerMoreSelect!: ViewContainerRef;
  
  public form!: FormGroup;

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formInit();
  }

  formInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      control1: new FormControl(),
    });
  }

  click() {
    this.form.addControl("control2", new FormControl());
    const component = this.containerMoreSelect.createComponent(SelectReteComponent);
    component.setInput("formGroup", this.form);
    component.setInput("formControlName", "control2");
    component.setInput("otherParam", "OK");
  }
}
```

**Child component**

```
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  Output,
  SimpleChanges,
} from "@angular/core";
import {
  AbstractControl,
  ControlContainer,
  FormGroup,
  FormGroupDirective,
} from "@angular/forms";
import { MatSelectChange } from "@angular/material/select";
import { ValueText } from "../models/value-text.model";

@Component({
  selector: "gcr-select-form",
  template: `<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select what you prefer</mat-label>
    <mat-select
      [formControlName]="formControlName"
      (selectionChange)="getSelection($event)">
      <mat-option></mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let value of values" [value]="value.id">
        {{ value.text}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>`,
  styles: ``,
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective,
    },
  ],
})
export class SelectReteComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() formGroup!: FormGroup;
  @Input() formControlName!: string;
  @Input() otherParam!: string;
  @Output() selected= new EventEmitter<ValueText>();
  constructor(private ValuesService: ValuesRepositoryService) {}

  /* Data are loaded from DB */

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    /* Other stuff */
    console.log("formGroup" + this.formGroup.controls); // I can see all control, control2 included
    console.log("formControlName " + this.formControlName); // It shows control2 correctly
    console.log("otherParam" + this.otherParam); // It shows "OK"
  }

  getSelection(event: MatSelectChange) {
    console.log("event.value " + event.value);
    this.selected.emit({
      value: event.value,
      text: event.source.triggerValue,
    });
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance,
Vincenzo

I tried to load the child component by passing the `FormGroup`, and I expected the `FormControl` to be recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refrain from using the directives for `@Input` or `@Output`, you are using `formControlName` as an input which is causing you bugs.

For this scenario, its best you go for `*ngFor` instead of view container ref, since its simpler, but I am providing both methods for you to review.

Using `ngFor`

```
    <div formArrayName="selectArr">
      <gcr-select-form *ngFor="let control of selectArrControls" [control]="control"
      ></gcr-select-form>
    </div>
```

For this particular scenario, if we pass the control as input we will be able to bind the select properly. Also its better you go for `formArray` instead of unique controls, since its more easily maintainable!

Also we need to do `useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormGroupDirective),` to prevent angular from throwing that error, it to refer to references which are not yet defined, when we use `forwardRef`.

Please find below working example!

main.ts

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { SelectReteComponent } from './child/child.component';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="selectArr">
              <gcr-select-form [control]="selectArrControls[0]"
              ></gcr-select-form>
            <ng-template #containerMoreSelect></ng-template>
            </div>
</form>
              <button mat-stroked-button (click)="click()">Add More</button>`,
  styles: [``],
  imports: [SelectReteComponent, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { showError: true },
    },
  ],
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('containerMoreSelect', {
    read: ViewContainerRef,
  })
  containerMoreSelect!: ViewContainerRef;

  public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    selectArr: new FormArray([new FormControl()]),
  });

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formInit();
  }

  formInit() {}

  get selectArr(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('selectArr') as FormArray;
  }

  get selectArrControls(): FormControl[] {
    return this.selectArr?.controls as FormControl[];
  }

  click() {
    const array = this.selectArr;
    array.push(new FormControl());
    const component =
      this.containerMoreSelect.createComponent(SelectReteComponent);
    component.setInput(
      'control',
      this.selectArrControls[this.selectArrControls.length - 1]
    );
    component.setInput('otherParam', 'OK');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideAnimations()],
});
```

child

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  forwardRef,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  Output,
  SimpleChanges,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  ControlContainer,
  FormArray,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormGroupDirective,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSelectChange, MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';

@Component({
  selector: 'gcr-select-form',
  imports: [MatSelectModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select what you prefer</mat-label>
    <mat-select
      [formControl]="control"
      (selectionChange)="getSelection($event)">
      <mat-option></mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let value of values" [value]="value.id">
        {{ value.text}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>`,
  styles: ``,
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormGroupDirective),
    },
  ],
})
export class SelectReteComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() control!: FormControl;
  @Input() formControlName!: number;
  @Input() otherParam!: string;
  @Output() selected = new EventEmitter<any>();
  values = [
    { id: 1, text: 'test' },
    { id: 2, text: 'test2' },
    { id: 3, text: 'test3' },
  ];
  form!: FormGroup;
  constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {}

  /* Data are loaded from DB */

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    /* Other stuff */
    // console.log('formGroup' + this.formGroup.controls); // I can see all control, control2 included
    // console.log('formControlName ' + this.formControlName); // It shows control2 correctly
    // console.log('otherParam' + this.otherParam); // It shows "OK"
  }

  getSelection(event: MatSelectChange) {
    console.log('event.value ' + event.value);
    this.selected.emit({
      value: event.value,
      text: event.source.triggerValue,
    });
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1nyxf2?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)